# How does iTunes Connect detect my app's minimum OS requirements?

Tags: iphone, app-store, deployment-target

I just submitted my iPhone application using iTunes Connect, but I don't see anywhere that they ask what version I used to compile my app?  The binary I submitted used the 3.0 SDK (I used the drop down menu on the top left corner of xcode), is that right?

How about the build settings? iPhone OS deployment Target and Base SDK? what value should I set there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS version is embedded in the Info.plist file of your application, and is taken from the Deployment Target setting of your project target. That will be the minimum OS your app will require in order to run. The Base SDK must be greater than or equal to the Deployment Target setting.

Note too that even if you never call one of the new iPhone OS 3.0 APIs (so your app would run fine on a device running OS 2.2.1) but set the Deployment Target to 3.0, the minimum required OS would be 3.0.

Comment: When is the version embedded into the Info.plist? I cannot see it in mine, even after building. Or is it something apple add if it's not there?

Comment: When you say "mine", do you mean the Info.plist in the project or the Info.plist in the final built artifact? XCode will not alter the one in the project but will merge it with other settings (such as the deplyment target) and output a final Info.plist in the built binary. If you're not seeing it there, then something's amiss.